# Is it possible to use Firebase Cloud Messaging API from an app that is not on the same GCloud Project?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-cloud-messaging, gcloud

I have a k8s app (let's call it App1) written in NodeJS that is sitting on a GCloud project (let's call it GCP1). App1 currently uses:

- a Cloud Datastore in another project (GCP2). App1 authenticates on GCP2 seamlessly, because App1's service account has the role *datastore.user* on GCP2;
- a Firebase Admin in another project (GCP3), that we use to send push notifications through FCM. App1 authenticates on GCP3 by using cert credentials stored in secret env vars.

I wanted to get rid of this hard-coded and potentially dangerous way of authenticate on GCP3, so I did what follows:

- I changed App1's Firebase Admin constructor from that:

```js
admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(SECRETS_HERE)
});
```

To that:

```js
admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.applicationDefault(),
    projectId: "GCP3_PROJECT_ID"
});
```

- I gave App1's SA the role *firebasenotifications.admin* on GCP3.

But this isn't working :( . I'm getting the following error:

> Credential implementation provided to initializeApp() via the "credential" property failed to fetch a valid Google OAuth2 access token with the following error: "Failed to parse access token response: Error: Server responded with status 403.

So my questions are:

- Is this even possible (use FCM API from another GCloud project)?
- If it is, how can I do that (or what am I doing wrong here)?
- Is it possible to test this scenario locally without necessarily have to generate/download/use GCP1's service account private key?
- If it is, how?

Answer (score 0):

It seems as though your app was already functional and you’re just making changes to enhance the security.

Regarding your questions:

- You can use the FCM API from [another project](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/multiprojects#use_multiple_projects_in_your_application). You can use multiple projects within an app.
- Your trouble seems to be the method that you are using to pass in your token.
- You need the private key for GCP1’s service account because GCP3 requires GCP1 for authentication purposes.

Can you please share more details regarding if you have the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` [environment variable set](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#initialize-sdk)? Can you also try running `firebase logout` and `firebase login`? This will validate that the environment variable is correctly configured as well as making sure that the correct account is logged in.

You can also read this documentation regarding working with [multiple Firebase projects in a single application](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/12/working-with-multiple-firebase-projects-in-an-android-app.html).

Comment: thanks for the reply! I'm not setting the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` env var: instead, I'm relying on App1 GKE service account roles that it has in other projects. This is working for the DataStore on GCP2, as I said. No credentials needed.
Maybe this don't work for Firebase, I'm thinking?